# Two consistently calls causes error - Received RST_STREAM with error code 2

Tags: objective-c, swift, grpc

I use Objective-C gRPC library (version 1.24.2) from Swift 5.0 code
I run the code on iOS 12.2.

Server was written on grpc-go v1.19.0

#### My protos:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package ...;

message Response {
    ServiceStatus status = 1;
}

message ResultStatus {
    Status status = 1;
}

enum Status {
    OK = 0;
    ...
}
```

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package ...;

message Feature {
    string name = 1;
    bool is_enabled = 2;
    int64 valid_until = 3;
}

message QueryFeatures {
}

message ResultFeature {
    common.ResultStatus status = 1;
    repeated Feature features = 2;
    reserved 3;
}

service FeatureTogglingService {
    rpc GetFeatures(QueryFeatures) returns (ResultFeature);
}
```

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package ...;

message CommandSendOnlineStatus {

}

service UserService {
    rpc SendOnlineStatus(CommandSendOnlineStatus) returns (Response);
}
```

#### What did I do?

I have a class which conforms to `GRPCProtoResponseHandler` protocol and it has a method `foo` which creates two services and calls one method from each service:

```swift
class MyClass: NSObject, GRPCProtoResponseHandler {
    var dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue {
        return .main
    }

    func foo() {
        let callOptions = GRPCMutableCallOptions()
        callOptions.initialMetadata = ["authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciO..."]

        featureService = FeatureTogglingService(host: "example.com:443", callOptions: callOptions)
        userService = UserService(host: "example.com:443", callOptions: callOptions)

        let userCall = userService?.sendOnlineStatus(withMessage: userRequest, responseHandler: self, callOptions: nil)
        let featureCall = featureService?.getFeaturesWithMessage(featureTogglingRequest, responseHandler: self, callOptions: nil)
        featureCall?.start()
        userCall?.start()
    }

    func didReceiveProtoMessage(_ message: GPBMessage?) {
    }

    func didClose(withTrailingMetadata trailingMetadata: [AnyHashable : Any]?, error: Error?) {
        print(" error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I call `foo` method.

#### What did I expect to see?

I expected to see two callings the method `func didClose(withTrailingMetadata trailingMetadata: [AnyHashable : Any]?, error: Error?)` with `error == nil`

#### What did I see instead?

I see two callings the method `func didClose(withTrailingMetadata trailingMetadata: [AnyHashable : Any]?, error: Error?)` where `error` contains:

```
 error: Optional(Error Domain=io.grpc Code=13 "{"created":"@1572546519.322425000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:...:443","file":".../Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}" UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
    date = "Thu, 31 Oct 2019 18:28:39 GMT";
    server = nginx;
}, io.grpc.TrailersKey={
}, NSDebugDescription={"created":"@1572546519.322425000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:...:443","file":".../Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}, NSLocalizedDescription=Received RST_STREAM with error code 2})
 error: Optional(Error Domain=io.grpc Code=13 "{"created":"@1572546519.322339000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:...:443","file":".../Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}" UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
    date = "Thu, 31 Oct 2019 18:28:39 GMT";
    server = nginx;
}, io.grpc.TrailersKey={
}, NSDebugDescription={"created":"@1572546519.322339000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:...:443","file":".../Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}, NSLocalizedDescription=Received RST_STREAM with error code 2})
```

But in server logs I see that every call went ok because response status 200. That's why I think there is a problem on client side in gRPC Objective-C library.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please drop a line here if you find the solution. I suspect that metadata is broken.